# How to reduce memory consumption of my winform application

Tags: c#, winforms, performance

## Background

I have a WinForm application which needs performance enhancement. I write a very large number of files(around 200-500kbs) which are protobuff serialized and written using the normal File.IO total size of those files go > 3Gb(the count is around 10,000). Now at a periodic frequency of 5 and 7 min, I read half files of them one by one and merge data and then serialize them again. As we all know this process consumes a very large amount Ram at the above-mentioned frequency.

## What I have tried

I came towards a solution about using [`Memory Mapped File`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile(v=vs.110).aspx)  and got below `test` code

## Writing

```
byte[] Buffer = GZipCompressor.ConvertToByteStream<OHLCData>(sampleObj);
using (MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("test", s.Length + 25))
{
    MemoryMappedViewAccessor accessor = mmf.CreateViewAccessor();
    accessor.Write(54, (ushort)Buffer.Length);
    accessor.WriteArray(54 + 2, Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length);
    Console.WriteLine(proc.PrivateMemorySize64 / 1024);
}
```

## Reading

```
using (MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("test", s.Length + 25))
{
   MemoryMappedViewAccessor accessor = mmf.CreateViewAccessor();
   ushort Size = accessor.ReadUInt16(54);
   byte[] buffer = new byte[Size];
   accessor.ReadArray(54 + 2, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
   Console.WriteLine(proc.PrivateMemorySize64 / 1024);
}
//then I convert the buffer back to class..
```

Now By using the above code, I am not able to achieve performance Improvement I am seeking for, My Ram usage is approx. same as previous(or at least not as per expectation).

I have another idea of creating a zip of file group using [Zip-Archive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive(v=vs.110).aspx) and assigning them to the `MMF`.

My question:

- is any of my above approach correct or can I have any other solution regarding this memory issue?

Note: Creating a dictionary for data and storing that dictionary is not feasible and possible for me as per my code structure.

Edit:- 
     Note in above sample I am not just appending data into end I have to make changes in previous data too, like removing the deprecated data form start.

Example representaion of task.

File stored:-

```
1,1
2,1 
3,1
4,1
```

Data to be merged:-

```
3,2
5,2
```

Final output :

```
 2,1
 3,3
 4,1
 5,2
```

Note in above example deprecated 1,1 is remove and 3,1 is updated to 3,3 and 5,2 is new element

Comment: Have you used a memory profiler to see what's taking up the memory?

Comment: There appears to be a fundamental flaw in your question, based on your comment `reating a dictionary for data and storing that dictionary is not feasible and possible for me as per my code structure.` If youre not willing to make changes in code structure, then there might not be anything else that cen be done for you

Comment: @SimonPrice I cant create a dictionary because after deserializing that dictionary both wanted and un-wanted data will be loaded in memory. Also In current scenario at a particular moment, there will only one 200kb file loaded in memory and by using dictionary whole dictionary will be memory lets say 1600 * 200.

Comment: @AKX yes we can conclude that my ram usage is highest during the merge phase.

Comment: Do you need to store the entire content of the file in memory for the merge in the dictionary being discussed? Just read the attributes you need for the merge, and the position of the record in the original file / the path to the original file.

Comment: But also, 1600x200kB is uhh 300MB memory usage which doesn't seem exorbitant if you're running this on a regular computer. (On shared webhosting or small VMs it might be a lot.)

Comment: @millimoose your solution may have worked in case of simple file appending , but in my case the situation is different, please see edit

Comment: So would it work if you also store the records to remove in another dictionary of just the record IDs? Like the fact you do have separate files for this data seems like it should simplify things somewhat, in that you only need to retain in memory for a long-term the list of references to the source files that will ultimately make up the result and only load the source files on demand. But I'm basing this on some wild guesses on what "merge" means and what ends up being output. Is it another bunch of files or one large file of the original records, or some entirely different structure?

Comment: @millimoose can you please see the edit so it may help understand what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Using a memory-mapped file to read files is generally a mistake, the file system cache already uses it so you double the RAM usage.  This code triples it by also allocating a byte[].  The 54 offset suggests that this is code to access a bitmap, the .NET Bitmap class already uses a memory mapped file under the hood.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for the info sir, can you tell me how I can achieve solution for my issue?

Comment: Just stop trying to micro-optimize the code, it didn't make it better.  I see no obvious reason why FileStream could not get this job done.

Comment: @HansPassant will file stream solve my ram issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hy, by reading your post I got a bit confused.

You are getting data that you serialize and store to the disk. This creates the following problem you have to load the data again this is one buffer then allocate or have a second buffer to deserialize. What would happen if you would save the data in an non serialized state?

The second thing that i got confused do you merge files that have been merged before? For example you get files foo1 and foo2 and merge them into file foo12, at some point in time later you get a third file foo3 and merge it to file foo12? In any case then you have a hefty memory consumption. Check your data if you can do bit packing or review data types that you do not need like reduce int to uint_8 or use something else.

If you use protobuf to serialize only to compress data this is not a good idea. There are compression algorithms that do that far better and very fast. Are you bound to the protobuf ?

One more question is why is your data not minimal. For example:

```
1,4
2,4
3,4
4,4
```

Could be:

```
T 4
1
2
3
4
```

With that you have less information to handle. Yes you have to keep track of some other stuff but nothing is perfect.

Comment: can you tell how can we save class data in a non-serialize format? also did you see my final output

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Something like this could function. But serializations are generally a conversions to string. So there should not be a problem.

https://eng.uber.com/trip-data-squeeze/
Please read this and use protobuf with zlib. I dont know how exactly this functions in C#.

Comment: "save the data in a non-serialized state" is a sentence that doesn't make sense in this context. Serialization isn't, not even "generally", a conversion to a (human-readable) string; it means, as the name suggests, the conversion of data that conceptually forms an graph - objects in memory with pointers between them - to a serial representation suitable for saving into a file which permits no other representation of data. ASN.1 encodings will generally produce binary chaos but they're definitely a method of serializing data.

Comment: The non-serializable attribute literally means "do not save this field".

Comment: @millimoose as hans said my current approach is wrong do you suggest any good solution for my issue?

Comment: @Lucifer I'm still very unsure of what you're actually trying to accomplish, how much of the input data changes in a single run and how much of it remains the same etc. But what I'd try to do is for the merge, only keep a representation of the changes you need to make to the output in memory - i.e. "remove record 1", "take record 3 from source file X at position Y, change value of second column to 3", "take record 5 from source file A at position B"; then go through this in the order in which it needs to be output, read the original records based on this, apply the merge change, write them out

Comment: @millimoose will give it a try

Comment: Like the *general* idea is that you don't try to store a dictionary of all the data in-memory, but that you still create some sort of index into the original storage that will let you efficiently access the original data record-by-record only when needed and keeping only the attributes you need in this index.

Comment: If you read a database systems textbook this is the basic principle of how database indices operate by the way. You have a bunch of files that store the full rows of a table/database in the order in which they were inserted into the table, and then you have an index, which is a separate data structure you can think of as a dictionary that maps the values of e.g. one column from a table to a file and a position in the big unorganized data file.

Comment: (And a bunch of complications thrown in, usually not even the index is small enough to retain in memory so it needs to be a data structure that can efficiently handle insertions and deletions in the middle while backed by slow storage, something like a B+ tree or a hash tree, but I digress. None of that is relevant to your case, because there's no reason why a dictionary with 1600 items cannot be kept in-memory if you manage to keep the values it holds smallish.)

Comment: @millimoose he is trying to minimize the memory consumption, then having an additional index table that is as big as the dictionary is not advantageous. But in general helps with processing speed. He is not building a database system because he would need to split his data to keep it in 3NF. And by the way I never said that you get a human readable string with serialization, but you get a compressed string where you know the structure. What you are mixing up is the encoding style or algorithm that gets involved to minimize the data amount stored.

Comment: @MarkoBencik as I understood his problem, he doesn’t want an index of key -> the entire contents of the source data file. What I’m proposing is an index of key -> (much) less than the entire contents of the source data, that allows fetching the original data if and when it’s ultimately needed during the final pass to flip the source records to the output. I.e. not loading and keeping all the input data in memory ever to begin with. This will actually hurt throughput, because you trade peak memory use for more I/O

Comment: I mentioned a database as an illustrative of how indices are used to do this sort of thing. It’s a mystery to me how you would, from this example, conclude I’m talking about something that adds to peak memory use. Surely you don’t believe database systems actually keep all their data *and* all the indices in memory?! One of the main functions of database systems is to allow for efficiently managing datasets too big to fit into memory! They do the opposite of what you’re describing!

Comment: And since I only mentioned it as an example of index use for a use case similar to the OPs, and never said anything about building a database, much less a relational database, I have no clue where 3NF comes from, a concept only relevant for modeling data in a relational DB. There’s no need to remodel the original data, all I’m talking about is storing only the fields from every given input file in memory that are necessary for the merge algorithm, in whichever representation is appropriate for the merging logic

Comment: The idea of Lucifer is for me clear minimize memory consumption if possible. The only possibility I see is to model the data to a minimal state. 

The problem with the indices is notorius and won't help Lucifer. The reason is he is merging data so he would need to merge or reindex his "tables". This takes time and it takes a lot of time to load the indices to memory. That is why the latency on the fist querry is huge and there are warm up procedures to solve those situations. But this is not here the topic.